# Indicial equations in Frobenius method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I don't have a very good intuition for how the Frobenius method came to be. I tried to solve a differential equation using the Frobenius method and I obtained multiple indicial equations corresponding to different powers of x. What am I supposed to do in this instance? My intuition tells me I should utilise the equation corresponding to the smallest power of x. However, I am not very confident about this since we haven't been explained how this method came to be (Compressed Semester because of COVID). Any help on the subject is appreciated.

The question is as follows- Solve the given ODE using the Frobenius method $x^2(x^2-1)y''-x(1+x^2)y'+(1+x^2)y=0$. In this ODE I obtained two indicial equations corresponding to the powers of $x^r$ and $x^{r+1}$ respectively. The equation for $x^r$ is $(1-r^2)=0$ and the equation corresponding to $x^{r+1}$ is $-r^2-2r=0$.  The roots of which of the above equations should I use to proceed further?

Comment: Could you share the problem and where you're stuck/confused?

Comment: The question is as follows- Solve the given ODE using the Frobenius method $x^2(x^2-1)y''-x(1+x^2)y'+(1+x^2)y=0$. In this ODE I obtained two indicial equations corresponding to the powers of $x^r$ and $x^(r+1)$ respectively. The equation for $x^r$ is $(1-r^2)=0$ and the equation corresponding to $x^(r+1)$ is $-r^2-2r=0$.  The roots of which of the above equations should I use to proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is that the first coefficient in the power series of the solution should be free. This in turn requires that the corresponding coefficient equation for the lowest degree only contains $a_0$ and that the coefficient of it is set to zero. That the first condition holds is a consequence of the conditions on a regular singularity.